# Photos on my iPhone 5 (101) but only the latest (23) show up in iCloud

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5 has 101 photos (& 7 videos) but on my PC > iCloud Photos > My Photo Stream only shows the last 23 of those photos.

Answer (score 1):

Photos in My Photo Stream are saved on the iCloud server for 30 days only.  If many of the photos are over 30 days old then they will no longer be available through PhotoStream:

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317

Comment: Also, videos are not uploaded to My Photo Stream.

Comment: Okay thanks. That jives with what I have in Favorites> Computer\iCloud Photos. Can you tell me how to get the other (78) photos (still on my phone) pushed to my PC? Into my folder "C:\Users\Bob\Pictures\iCloud Photos\My Photo Stream" and will those photos disappear after 30 days too?